# How do I hide a canvas or any other object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

So I have a main canvas with three canvases on it. and a text.

```html
<canvas id="Background" width="350" height="300"
style="border:6px solid black; position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;">
</canvas>

<canvas id="Canvas1" width="150" height="100"
style="border:6px solid blue; position: absolute; left: 33px; top: 20px;">
</canvas>

<canvas id="Canvas1" width="50" height="50"
style="border:6px solid yellow; position: absolute; left: 33px; top: 200px;">
</canvas>

<canvas id="Canvas1" width="150" height="100"
style="border:6px solid blue; position: absolute; left: 33px; top: 20px;">
</canvas>

<canvas id="Canvas1" width="150" height="100"
style="border:6px solid blue; position: absolute; left: 243px; top: 20px;">
</canvas>

</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 70px; top: 50px;">
<p> example </p>
</div>
```

Later ill be adding `onclick` event and when I click, I want the text and one of the canvases to disappear. Basically I want to know how to show/hide items in this code. Thank you!

Comment: Id should be unique, and I guess your question is probably duplicated but this should help you: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: It's worth noting that you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID in the DOM.

Comment: I don't know why it says my question is duplicated but yes thanks, I'll use that link as reference to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css properties `visibility` or `display` to achieve this.
In your code if you want to hide the text, just give text div an id of `text` like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 70px; top: 50px;" id="text">
  <p> example </p>
</div>
```

and define a function in your script file or tag like this:

```
function hideElement () {
  document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none'

  // For Canvas1

 document.getElementById('Canvas1').style.display = 'none'
}

hideElement()
```

Comment: Not only is that useful, I also did not know how to create a function with it... but now I do. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 2):

Use either `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. The difference is that `display: none` completely removes the item from view, while `visibility: hidden` preserves the empty space where the element would have been. Which is appropriate depends on your use case.

JS looks roughly like `document.getElementById("Canvas1").style.display = "none";`

Comment: The complicity of it is insane. Thanks for that man!